# Missing External Hard Disk

Tags: mount, hard-drive

Ok... did something stupid... 'lil help?

I have an external 2TB hard drive that had a really long name attached to my ubuntu 16.04 dual boot (WIN10) machine.  I wanted to shorten the name so I used the disks utility (gui) to change the name of the drive to something shorter.  Worked... momentarily.

After a reboot, the drive can not be found and/or mounted.

at `/mnt` I see `wwn-0x5000c500a998b400-part1`

at `/media/myusername` I see nothing.  I re-opened the disk utility and installed gparted, neither of them even acknowledge that the external drive is connected to the computer... whoops...

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd check your `/etc/fstab` to see how you have it there. I usually mount drives with UUID as its static (set on formatting), but if you'd used the name to mount, it won't remount until you make fstab match the new name. *all this assumes you mounted it automatically using fstab (file system table)*

Comment: Yeah, I just checked.. no record of it in the file...  drive still works and appears under old name.. in Windows.. :-(

Comment: You probably mounted it using gui.  I'm not the best person to help with that (*I never do it.  I'd be more likely to use commands `blkid` etc. to get info, then add entry in fstab to have it load on boot/login*)

Comment: I mounted like usual... plugged it in... frustrating to see the drive still work on windows... no answer here I will have to re-format a 2TB drive.. any suggestions welcome

Comment: I'd suggest you not be hasty, and be patient. The only help I could be would be `lsblk` to list block device to check system can see it, `blkid` to get the UUID (what i'd use; you could use info from `lsblk` but it leads to issues like this sometimes) then add the detail to `fstab`.  My expectation was you would 'glean' this if you knew enough, but feel more its knowledge you don't have, and I don't want to write a long example 'answer' to walk you thru it.  Just because I won't. if you wait someone else will do it (*or go find a prior walk thru on mounting partitions; common & ~easy*)

Comment: Solved it... for some reason the actual USB slot went dead (tested it with a different working external drive)... googled a bit... I ended up running `dmesg | tail -n 20`  sorted everything out.. works perfectly now